# Android:open fragment from Navigation drawer

Tags: android

i created a navigation drawer and a fragment i tried to open that fragment from the navigation drawer but nothing happen any help please..

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment;
    switch(position){
        case 0: //search//todo
            break;
        case 1: //stats
            break;
        case 2: //my account //todo
            break;
        case 3: //settings //todo
            break;
        case 4: //location //todo
            fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(LocationFragment.TAG);
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = new LocationFragment();
            }
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, LocationFragment.TAG).commit();
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed some of your code and this should work. Feel free to comment if any issues occur. You can't find your Location fragment because you haven't `setTag` for it.

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment;
    String fragmentName;
    switch(position) {
        case 0: //search//todo
            fragment = new SearchFragment();
            fragmentName = "SearchFragment";
            break;
        case 1: //stats
            fragment = new StatFragment();
            fragmentName = "StatFragment";
            break;
        case 2: //my account //todo
            fragment = new MyAccountFragment();
            fragmentName = "MyAccountFragment";
            break;
        case 3: //settings //todo
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            fragmentName = "SettingsFragment";
            break;
        case 4: //location //todo
            fragment = new LocationFragment();
            fragmentName = "LocationFragment";
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentName).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is many errors under mDrawerList , mDrawerLayout , mDrawerRelativeLayout and the fragmentName too